# Probability of subevents

Tags: probability, probability-theory, card-games

How to compute the probability of sub-events given that we only have the events probabilities?

An example to clarify, drawing cards: 
    We consider two cards at a time, assume we are given the following: Probability that we have two hearts is $p_{hh},$ one heart and one spades is $p_{hs},$ heart and clubs $p_{hc}$ and heart and diamonds $p_{hd}.$
    And similarly for all other pairs we can consider. But the question is: how from these probabilities (describing events of pairs of cards) can we compute
the probability of having a card of hearts? (i.e. now we're looking into single card events, I know the answer in this example is trivial because we just have 13/52, but I'm trying to learn how it can be computed as a subevent
given that we know the probability of a larger event. I imagine a simple union of the four events will not give the correct answer, or does it? I mean $p_h = p_{hh}+p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd}$ is very likely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> An example to clarify, drawing cards: 
>       We consider two cards at a time, assume we are given the following: Probability that we have two hearts is $p_{hh},$ one heart and one spades is $p_{hs},$ heart and clubs $p_{hc}$ and heart and diamonds $p_{hd}.$
>       And similarly for all other pairs we can consider. But the question is: how from these probabilities (describing events of pairs of cards) can we compute
>   the probability of having a card of hearts? (i.e. now we're looking into single card events, I know the answer in this example is trivial because we just have 13/52, but I'm trying to learn how it can be computed as a subevent
>   given that we know the probability of a larger event. I imagine a simple union of the four events will not give the correct answer, or does it? I mean $p_h = p_{hh}+p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd}$ is very likely wrong.

Nope, it is correct.   However, $13/52$ is wrong.

If $p_{hd}$ is the probability of selecting one heart and one diamond *in either order* when selecting two cards from a standard deck, and so on, then $p_{hh}+p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd}$ *is* the probability of selecting *at least* one heart when selecting two cards.

Where as $p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd}$ is the probability of selecting exactly one heart.

---

$$p_{hh} = 1/17, p_{hd}=p_{hs}=p_{hc}=13/102\\~\\ p_{hh}+p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd} = 15/34\\~\\ p_{hs}+p_{hc}+p_{hd} = 13/34$$

---

The probability of not selecting any hearts is ${19}/{34}$

---

$$p_{hh}=\dfrac{\binom{13}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}} = \frac 1{17}\\p_{hs}=\dfrac{\binom{13}{1}\binom{13}{1}}{\binom{52}{2}} = \frac{13}{102}\\p_h = \dfrac{\binom{52}{2}-\binom{39}{2}}{\binom{52}{2}} = 1-\frac{19}{34} = \frac{15}{34}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your wonderful explanations, very clear. I agree completely, but I may have poorly phrased my question: you correctly show what the probability of a heart is in a *two* card selection, whereas by $p_h$ I meant the probability of a heart in a *single* selection. In view of that, I m trying to understand how single card probabilities can be inferred given to us only two card probs. Would you be so kind to add a word about this?

Comment: Ah, then, no, you cannot infer single selection card probabilities when *only* given double selection probabilities.  You have to go back to the model of "how cards are selected".

Comment: Oh okay :(  I don't know why I thought since it's subsystem it should be retrievable. A last thought if I may: say we are sampling the deck of cards by indeed drawing randomly two cards each time and writing down the results and put them back in and redraw: say we repeat this process many times, now from the result we have essentially estimated $p_{hh}$, $p_{hs}$ and so on. Now we ask: what is the relative frequency (or probability) with which each card of hearts was visited? (Given that we had repeated the process long enough we expect these frequencies to be uniform aming all 13 hearts).

Comment: Would there be a way to estimate these aforementioned frequencies from the double card probabilities that we have estimated?

Comment: I have a question about normalization: so if $a=p_{hh}+p_{hs}+p_{hd}+p_{hc}$ is the probablity of drawing at least one heart, and  $b=p_{ch}+p_{cs}+p_{cd}+p_{cc}$ the probability of drawing a club card and similarly for the two other card types,  lets denote them by c and d. But in defining them in this way, do we still have a+b+c+d=1? Or they re not supposed to add up to 1? Thx for any help

Comment: @user929304 No they will not add to $1$.  The events are not mutually exclusive (aka disjoint). Since you may draw one heart and one club, etc, at the same time, the events overlap.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think it really depends on the nature of your experiment. For example, drawing two cards are not independent, while for some other experiments we may have independent experiments. But here is an approach. You can have the following relations.

$P(hh)=P(h_1)\times P(h_2\mid h_1)$

Where $P(h_2\mid h_1)$ is the probability of getting a heart in the second draw, given we have drawn a heart in the first draw.

Likewise, you can have

$P(hs)=P(h_1)P(s_2|h_1)+P(s_1)P(h_2|s_1)$

You have $10$ such equations, if you do not have any orders in double draws. Then, you can obviously see that you need conditional probabilities like $P(h_2|s_1)$ and there are $4^2=16$ possible conditional probabilities. adding the single probabilities, you have a total of $20$ unknowns. From an information theoretic point of view, you do not have enough information to find single draw probabilities. However, having certain conditions, like independency of drawings, you might be able to get rid of some unknowns and get what you want.

Comment: "Where P(h|h) is the probability of getting a heart in the second draw, given we have drawn a heart in the first draw" Ouch! Terrible notation, if h is not the same as h...

Comment: @Did, sorry. I had something in my mind that was presented in a bad way. I made an edit. Please let me know if it is still not clear

Comment: @Med It is clearer if you subscript *the events*.

Comment: I ve read your answer again, i find it more and more useful. I ll keep pondering this and get back to you. Thx again

Comment: @user929304, I am glad you find it useful.